# Limits question

Tags: calculus

I've spent the last couple of days working through a chapter on countable and uncountable sets in an introductory real analysis text. I'm still in the process of thinking through everything, and I've got a question that's stumped me (Apologies if this is a silly question).

Consider $$f(x)= \frac {\sin(n \pi x)}{x}, n \in \Bbb N.$$ For any $n$, there are $2n$ roots within the interval $[-1, 0) \cup (0, 1].$ Is it true that as we let $n \to \infty,$ we are restricting *all* the roots to lie within the interval $[-1, 0) \cup (0, 1]?$ What then becomes of the function on the interval $( -\infty, -1) \cup (1, \infty)$?

I think the answer is that although it is true that as $n \to \infty$ we are restricting all the roots to lie within $[-1, 0) \cup (0, 1],$ we can't examine the behavior of the function when all the roots lie within $[-1, 0) \cup (0, 1]$, as this would mean that $n=\infty$, which isn't possible; $\infty$ isn't a real number. We can only consider what happens as $n \to \infty$, with emphasis on the word "*as*." And as long as $n \in \Bbb N$, there remain roots of $f(x)$ on the interval $( -\infty, -1) \cup (1, \infty)$, so that there's nothing strange about the function on that interval.

Is this correct?

Comment: You'll find it less confusing to include $n$ in the notation for $f$, preferably as a subscript: $f_n(x)=\sin(n\pi x)/x$. Now we can make precise statements like the following: for all $n$, we have $f_n(2) = 0$, so $f_n$ has a zero in $(1,\infty)$. I don't know if that's your real question, but it's a start!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f_n = \frac{\sin(n\pi x)}x$.
It is true that there are $2n$ roots of $f_n$ in $[-1, 1] - \{0\}$.
I feel, however, that the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty} 2n = \infty$ does not convey the same meaning as restricting all roots to be within $[-1, 1]$. Here's an informal explanation.

Let $a_n$ be the number of roots of $f_n$ in $[-1, 1]$ and
$b_n$ be the number of roots of $f_n$ not in $[-1, 1]$.
For each $n$, we have $a_n = 2n$ and $b_n = \infty$.
Your claim that eventually all roots must be in $[-1, 1]$ is, in a sense, equivalent to saying that
$b_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.
This is obviously not true because $b_n = \infty$ for all $n$.

Comment: So,  $b_n = \infty$ for all $n,$  and $a_n \to \infty $ as $n \to \infty$? So it's like removing all the even number from $\Bbb N$: we're simply dividing a countably infinite set (here, $b_n$) into two countably infinite sets ($ b_n$ and $ a_n$)?

Comment: @Ryan What is different here is that all $a_n$ are finite, but the set of even numbers is infinite. The set of roots $S_n = \{x \in \mathbb R \mid f(x) = 0\}$ actually grows, but its growth cannot be measured by "size", as all $S_n$ have the same size as $\mathbb Z$. The growth of $S_n$, however, can be measured by inclusion because $S_n \subset S_{n+1}$. Very informally, $S_n$ doubles in size as $n$ increases by $1$. The same is true for $A_n = S_n \cap [-1, 1]$ and $B_n = S_n - A_n$. That means $B_n$ grows at the same rate as $A_n$, but it starts at a much bigger size.

Comment: You could say that the problem here comes from identifying infinite sets with their cardinalities. To make proper claims about zeros of $f_n$, you might want to consider the set of zeros instead of the number of zeros. You can even define $S_\infty = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty S_n$, $A_\infty = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ and $B_\infty = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$ without knowing that $f_n$ converges (which is not the case). What you did wrong could be viewed as subtracting "sizes" of $A_\infty$ from $S_\infty$ and take that as $|B_\infty| = \infty - \infty = 0$.